# VS doesn't do up-to-date check before building project, just rebuilds it

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I've set verbosity for build output to diagnostic.
In other projects when you starting build, in output you can see that before building, vs does up-to-date check and says why project needs to rebuild, like:

> Build started...
> 1>------ Up-To-Date check: Project: ConsoleApplication3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
> 1>Project is not up-to-date: build input 'c:\users\admin\source\repos\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp' was modified after the last build finished.
> 1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
> 1>Search paths being used for ...

I'm building Unreal Engine 4 from source code, and it rebuilds it every time, and there is nothing in output

> Build started...
> 1>------ Build started: Project: UE4, Configuration: Development_Editor x64 ------
> 1>Search paths being used for...

Comment: Could you share the UE4 sample with us?

Comment: well I redownloaded code and it worked, no idea what was wrong with that project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the build log in my side for UE4 project.

[image]

The project has the log for `up-to-date` check. So maybe there is something with your project itself or VS Environment.

Try:

**1)** reset all vs settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset vs settings**

**2)** disable any third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed**

**3)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the UE4 solution folder and any output files

then restart VS to test your project again.

**Besides**, you could try to re-download the UE4 code and then test the new one to check it.